# Pass more than two parameters to selector, which made from string

Tags: ios, swift, parameters, selector

I have some functions with more than two parameters. And I need call it from Selector. How can I pass it to Selector?

Swift can't get more than two parameters.
In self.perform I can't pass all arguments with array or dictionary.

```swift
@objc func myFunc(name: String, surname: String, phone: String) {
    print("my func with name: \(name), surname: \(surname) and phone: \(phone)")
}

Selector("myFuncWithName:surname:phone:")
```

Maybe somebody can help me write it without Selector, or some other ways.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to use `perform`? Show what you are really trying to do so a proper solution can be offered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing a dictionary `[String:AnyObject]` to the function and then inside the function iterate for the different keys.